# Overwrite posts/pages via import

Tags: posts, pages, import, export

I have a bunch of live sites that I'm debating bringing into a multisite installation. It would take a bit to set up and configure, of course, and ideally I'd do it locally over a period of time, then upload somewhere.

Of course, these sites are still live, and are still being updated, some on a daily basis.

Is there a way to import pages/posts so that *changes are overwritten*? So let's say the "About" page is changed live - I want to bring it into my test site while it's in development.

Or in other words - I don't want to lose any live content changes while the site is in development.

What's my best method of doing this?

Comment: To be clear do you mean that you want to import&overwrite from production single site to a dev multisite? That might be messy...

Comment: heh I know :P i'm just trying to figure out a way to maintain the content while working on it in a dev environment.

Comment: Typically I would recommend to just copy whole database over, but it won't fit single/multi mismatch.

Comment: hmm, would it make sense to just copy over wp_posts? (and of course, rename it to whatever site ID the site in question had)

Comment: i feel like there should be a functionality like this, even if just single-site to single-site, to the basic WP export plugin...

Answer (score -1):

A good way around this I've found is to modify your local `wp-config.php` to access the remote database directly. You often have to enable `remote sql` in CPANEL. Then you enter the remote host URL in the `define('DB_HOST', 'yoursite.com');` part of the config.

Comment: I don't see how this will help said user import pages from one install to another. Could you edit your answer and expand on this further ( by clicking the `edit` link above )?